# SQlite foreign key logic

Tags: database, sqlite

I am using SQlite and the PK column seems to be auto-incrementing. I am a bit concerned about following approach where I want to normalize the `type`-column:

```
Table: Book
id   type  name
...  ...   ...
15    1     Foo
16    2     Bar
...   ...  ...


Table: Type
id  typename
1   magazine
2   novel
```

What happens, if I recreate the `Type`-table and the PK-index (="id") changes, e.g. that `1` now refers to `novel` instead of `magazine`. So to be more robust, I am thinking about inserting a custom second column that contains the "logical" indices that I refer to:

```
Table: Book
id   type  name
1    3     Foo
2    4     Bar

Table: Type
id   type  typename
1    3     magazine
2    4     novel
```

This way my custom type-ids would be independent from the primary keys. I think another advantage of the last approach is that I would not have to re-ask the latest (new) `id` of a new row, because I would refer to the `type` column that I know before. This way when I insert the row I already know the "type" id to make references (I am using threads for the database, so reading a value from the database within a method is difficult or not possible (?) - so if I would need the id, I would have to ask the db first).

Is this a legit approach? Or should I directly create a non-incrementing primary key with my "custom id's" that I manage on my own?

Comment: _"What happens, if I recreate the Type-table and the PK-index (="id") changes, e.g. that 1 now refers to novel instead of magazine"_ Then you're importing the data wrong. A good SQL dump should restore the proper primary keys.

Comment: I used to create a separate column, but I've found that usually it's simpler just to use the primary key as the foreign key. What's your plan for recreating the table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As shown in the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html), you can simply insert the desired values in the PK column:

```
INSERT INTO Type(id, typename) VALUES(2, 'novel')
```

And if you never need autoincrement values, you should not use an autoincrementing column in the first place.

Comment: let's not confuse `sqlite`'s behaviour of incrementing a PK if not inserted explicitly(which is what OP is experiencing) and the `sqlite` special `autoincrement` feature which is what your link points to.

Comment: @ChristopherPearson This answer, and the page I linked to, apply to *both* kinds of autoincrementing columns. Where exactly is the confusion?

Comment: d'oh, I must have been really tired last night...  I literally must have only read the section on the `autoincrement` keyword.  my apologies.